# Snowplow NodeJS Tracker: snowplow-tracker vs snowplow-tracker-core

Tags: analytics, web-analytics, snowplow

We have an NodeJS - Express application on top of which we have implemented Snowplow analytics, and are migrating away from Google Analytics. We want to now configure a JS Tracker in the NodeJS code. We are having difficulty choosing between the two available NodeJS trackers.

My question is - what are the differences between the two `snowplow-tracker-*` npm modules? I understand that `snowplow-tracker` is a more detailed implementation with more abstraction. But what are the features or level of complexity one should look at when choosing one over the other?

I'm looking at :

1. Complexity of application
2. Performance overhead between the two npm packages
3. Any particular features excluded from `snowplow-tracker-core` that one might want to use

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this on the [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snowplow-user/CXfAy1iz7_w). My answer:

The core module contains shared functionality used by the client-side JavaScript Tracker, the snowplow-tracker module, and the Segment.io integration. It isn't really intended to be used directly and excludes some fairly important functionality, like methods to actually send events. You should probably use the snowplow-tracker module, also known as the Node.js Tracker.